# How to exit case expression as soon as my condition becomes true for one of the row in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

[image]

Above is my config file and i have another data set from which mandatory column to match with this config files are col1, col2 and col3.

If my above 3 column matches then i am using case expressions for col4 and col5.

```
Case when col5 = data from main dataset and col4 = data from main dataset then col6

Case when col5 = data from main dataset and col4 != data from main dataset then col6

Case when col5 != data from main dataset and col4 = data from main dataset then col6

Case when col5 != data from main dataset and col4 != data from main dataset then col6
```

The above case statements I don't want to run for all the above data. If my first case statement is true for any row then I should take its corresponding value from col6 and exit the case.

Suppose my first case expression is true for the first row in my above data set then I should get the result as 4 and the case should stop executing for other rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from t
where col1 = ? and col2 = ? and col3 = ?
order by (case when col5 = data and col4 = data then 1
               when col5 = data then 2
               when col4 = data then 3
               else 4
          end)
limit 1;
```

If you want this for each `col1`/`col2`/`col3` combination, use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (col1, col2, col3) t.*
from t
order by col1, col2, col3,
         (case when col5 = data and col4 = data then 1
               when col5 = data then 2
               when col4 = data then 3
               else 4
          end)
limit 1;
```

Comment: thanks but on basis of col4 and col5 i need to get the value from col6.. Suppose case when col5 = data and col4 = data is true then I should get 4 from col6 and stop the case statements to run for other rows. Output should be just 4 then

Comment: @abc . . . Both of these return `col6`.  If that is the only column you want, then just use `select col6` in the first query.